# Set $A$ dominates set $B$ and set $B$ dominates set $A$

Tags: real-analysis, logic

By the definition, $A$ and $B$ are sets of real numbers and set $A$ dominates set $B$ if for every $a\in A$, there exists $b\in B$ such that $a<b$. I have to find 2 non-empty sets where:

- $A\bigcap B$ is empty
- $A$ dominates $B$
- $B$ dominates $A$

From what I understand, for the greatest element of $A$, there exists a greater element in $B$, and for the greatest element in $B$, there exists a greater element in $A$, which looks like a contradiction. What is wrong with my reasoning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
$$A= [0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q} \quad \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad \quad B=[0,1) \cap \left( \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}\right)$$

(what is wrong in your reasoning is the fact that you are talking about the *greatest* element of $A$, which does not necessarily exist)